# What is this word at the beginning of this audio?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, audio

I can't work it out. It's mentioned so many times in this audiobook, but I don't know what it is. Please help.

The first 5 seconds or so should be enough to get it.

This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wlkj6uJzJjw

It starts:

'Dies ist eine Liebelwochs aufname'

Translating to:

'This is a "something" admission'

What is this "something"?

Thanks in advance for the help

---

Also in future, what should I do if I come up against this type of situation again?

What are good ways of figuring out the word by myself?

Comment: *Aufnahme* would translate to *recording* here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really a bit hard to understand the first time but he repeats the word a few times. It's [librivox](https://librivox.org/).

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibriVox):

> LibriVox is a group of worldwide volunteers who read and record public domain texts creating free public domain audiobooks for download from their website and other digital library hosting sites on the internet.

The sentence he says is:

> This is a librivox recording; all librivox recordings are in the public domain and are public property.

Comment: Thanks so much, the audiobook was saying it so many times and it was driving me nuts not knowing what it was

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it is really hard, I know exactly what you mean.

Comment: @PerlDog you are welcome. It is always a pleasure, when one does not need to write a new answer and can slightly edit an existing one :D