# Identify a conversation

Tags: listening-comprehension, audio, conversation

Could someone please tell me what they are saying in 00:07 in this audio file? Thanks in advance

https://sndup.net/88k4

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unlikely to be of use for anybody else (providing no useful search terms either.) I consider this as equivalent to translation (here more appropriate: transcription) of an individual text.

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. What did you transcribe on your own? (Closing with the same reason as here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/31463/what-is-this-word-at-the-beginning-of-this-audio?rq=1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- "Grüss dich Anna, das ist Arnia"
- "Tag Sabira"
- "Hallo Arnia"

A conversation of *several people* who **introduce** themselves and **greet** them.

*I don't know whether "Sabira" or "Sabina" was said...*

Comment: confirming "Sabira", suggesting "Amir": Anna is greeting both Sabira and Amir.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it the help.